# Is it possible to create a firewall rule accepting calls from a Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

In a single Google Cloud Project, I have a MongoDB instance, and a cloud function that interacts with it.

For obvious reasons, I would like to avoid exposint the MongoDB server to the outer internet.

If the cloud function was on a VM, I would just create a firewall rule to open the MongoDB port to this VM IP address only.

How can I do that for a Cloud Function?

Comment: There are not static IPs for Cloud Functions.  You should assume they will change over time.

Comment: Thanks Doug and sorry for the duplicate. So there's no way to restrict access to a cloud function?

Comment: From a network routing perspective, no.